# How to get started with jtransforms library in Java

Tags: java, fft, wav, frequency-analysis, pitch-detection

I want to extract frequencies from a wav audio and i'm thinking of using an autocorrelation method along with the usage of FFT.

Came accross a good pitch detection library for java called "JTransforms" can anyone suggest how to get started with it? Code snippets would be ideal.

Thanks

Comment: Did you search right here on StackOverflow first ? There are a lot of questions and answers on this very subject already. Look at "Related questions" on the right of the page, and questions such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699360/audio-analysis-frequency-vs-pitch). Try also searching SO for `pitch [jtransforms]` or `fft [jtransforms]`.